# How to edit .aspx page in Chrome

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome, html, edit

A webpage I'm accessing via Chrome, has a countdown timer which refreshes and updates the page/data every 10 minutes. I would like to edit the page locally to change this update frequency. Using the Developer Tools, I've found the variable which needs changing:

```
var updatefreq = 600;
```

However, it seems I'm unable to do any edits. Under Sources in Chrome Developer Tools, I can edit various bits of javascript code, however the page is in .aspx, and I can't seem to edit it. Is it possible to get around this?

Comment: You can't modify websites you don't have access to. You need to get the file via FTP, modify the file and save it back. Dev tools are only for small local debugging, nothing else.

Comment: Please give the URL and the line number - I'd like to have a go.

Comment: @walther: I don't want to modify the website so that everyone will be affected by this change, only the instance when it runs in my browser. Perhaps this is not possible.

Comment: @Andrew: How can I send you a PM?

Answer (score 0):

Under the sources section of DevTools Click on pause script execution.  It's on the right column at the top.  It is the button farthest to the left border of the right column that looks like two vertical bars.  [The keyboard shortcut is `f8`]

Comment: I had tried this earlier, and just tried it again. However it doesn't work. Thanks anyway.